# how to configure a post request with a query parameter in flutter

Tags: flutter, http-post

I want to make a post request which require a model class and a query parameter.I want to pass a query parameter for the email after I have also passed the model class. I am coming from Java background and in Java, you can just use @Query keyword then pass the name of the key for it. I want to achieve the same thing using flutter.
This is how the backend is configured.

```
PostMapping("/account/create")
    public ResponseEntity<SignUpResponse> createAccount(@RequestBody BankAccountDto bankAccountDto, @RequestParam("email") String email) throws DataNotFoundException, DataNotAcceptableException, DataAlreadyExistException, DataNotFoundException, DataNotAcceptableException, DataAlreadyExistException {
        return bankAccountService.createAccount(bankAccountDto,email);
```

This is what I tried

```
static Future<Response?> postData(String endpoint, dynamic body) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + endpoint);
    Map<String, String> header = <String, String>{
      'Authorization': 'Bearer',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    };
    try {
      Response response =
          await post(url, body: json.encode(body), headers: header);
      print("The post response returns ${response.body}");
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this way, it alot cleaner in my opinion

```
static Future<Response?> postData(String endpoint, dynamic body) async {
    //var url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + endpoint);
    Map<String, String> header = <String, String>{
      'Authorization': 'Bearer',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    };
    try {
      final String authority = "exemple.com";
      // Here your api endpoint
      final String path = "/api/account/create";
      final queryParameters = {"email": "your_email_here"};

      final uri = Uri.https(authority, path, queryParameters);

      Response response = await post(uri, body: json.encode(body), headers: header);
      print("The post response returns ${response.body}");
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a query parameter just add it to the URL

```dart
var query = "?email=$email";
var url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + endpoint + query);
```

If you want to add `email` to the body, just do something like this

```dart
Map bodyMap = jsonEncode(body);
bodyMap["email"] = email;
Response response =
          await post(url, body: bodyMap, headers: header);
```